# Objective C - After present modal view the root controller is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

The first view's name is `IntroPage`.
The second view's name is `Search`.
In the `viewDidAppear` I'm using this code:

```
Search *search = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchPage"];
search.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:search animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Everything is ok but when I want to see the current view

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

He shows me that the current view is "Intro" instead "Search" and it causes a lot of bugs.

when I'm changing the code to this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SearchPage" sender:self];
```

the problem is solved but I can't use this code because I need to add more properties with the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the code you added, the `Search` will be a modalViewController of Intro. It doesn't mean that `search` will be a rootViewController.

If you want to change rootViewController, you have to set Search as a rootViewController.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:search];
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful!. is it ok to do like this:
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = search;
?

Comment: @user3481741 It'll work in most case; however not recommended. In some case such as UIAlertView is on the screen, the UIAlertView's layout window will be the KeyWindow. If appDelegate has a window property, direct access to the property is better. `[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:search]`

Comment: Ok got it. last question :)
the KeyWindow is the current view ?

Comment: And if it true, how do I get the KeyWindow?
because until now, when i wanted to get the current view I asked this in the AppDelegate:
if([self.window.rootViewController isMemberOfClass:[searchPage class]])

Comment: The keyWindow is not a view. [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/keyWindow) and [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)